# How to handle exceptions from async method with using Enterprise Library?

Tags: c#, exception, enterprise-library

`ExceptionCallHandler` is default exception call handler in Enterprise Library, but it doesn't work with async methods.

How should I rewrite this handler that to work with async methods?

It is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
        {
            if (input == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
            if (getNext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("getNext");
            IMethodReturn methodReturn = getNext()(input, getNext);

            MethodInfo methodInfo = input.MethodBase as MethodInfo;
            bool isTask = methodInfo != null && typeof(Task).IsAssignableFrom(methodInfo.ReturnType);
            Task continueTask = null;

            if (isTask)
            {
                Task task = methodReturn.ReturnValue as Task;
                if (task != null)
                {
                    continueTask = task.ContinueWith((t) =>
                    {
                        if (t.Exception != null)
                        {
                            methodReturn.Exception = t.Exception.Flatten().InnerException;
                        }
                    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                }
            }

            if (continueTask != null)
            {
                continueTask.Wait();
            }

            HandleMethodReturnException(methodReturn, input);


            return methodReturn;
        }
```

Comment: Code has been adeed

Comment: Move your handler into the continuation.